# Как реализуется приватность?

Tags: jquery, php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Вот мне очень интересно как реализуется приватность. Например есть два юзера. один юзер хочет скрыть блок друзей или фото, как вот такое вот реализуется. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вопрос по какому-то конкретному CMS или просто интересует как реализовано у других?
Вообще реализаций масса, мне больше нравится делать права в бит маске, hex в базе данных занимает минимум места и в нем помещается целая куча различных прав.

Comment: Если кратко: контенту проставляются права доступа, при запросе контента юзер проверяется на наличие этих прав, в случае отсутствия выдается какая-нибудь заглушка.

Comment: @Awesome интересно вот как у других реализовано и как вообще реализуется.

Comment: Все зависит от того насколько гибко вам нужно сделать права доступа, если очень гибко тогда рекомендую почитать про бинарные права, если просто скрыть 1 раздел от пользователей не являющихся его владельцем можно просто добавить в таблице с разделами флаг приватности и при получении контента проверять если ли флаг и является ли пользователь который обратился к контенту его владельцем, далее уже в связи с результатом проверки отдаем контент пользователю или не отдаем, также можно отдать вместо контента визуальную ошибку в запрете доступа к данному разделу например.

Comment: @Awesome Спасибо вам большое понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что то типа этого (это псевдокод, реальная реализация зависит от движка, который вы используете):

```
..................................
if( $database_result['private'] == ONLY_FRIENDS ) {
    if( $user->checkFriend($database_result['photo_owner']) // Проверим имеет ли пользователь право просматривать приватные фото, если true выведем фотку
        $page->createPhoto($current_photo);
    else // иначе выведем предупреждение, что у него недостаточно прав
        $echo '<p>Доступ к этой фотографии вам закрыт<\p>';
}
..............................
```

Comment: Спасибо большое буду разбираться.